# Remove blank lines from copied Text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code that works perfect except the spacing. The whole point of this code is to create something that allow me to add text to a textarea, then copy it with the empty lines removed.

Example:
Inputted text =
Line 1

Line 2

Copied/outputted text =
Line1
Line2

I've tried line spacing in both text area and DIV and onclick OR

> onchange ="this.value=this.value.replace(/\n\r/gi,'');">

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.content:not(.focus)').keyup(function(){                    

    var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');

    $('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>'));

    })

  });//]]> 

</script>

<body>

  <textarea name="mas" rows="15" class="content" ></textarea>

  <div class="mas" >
    <pre contenteditable="true" id="p1" >Text</pre>
  </div>

  <button onclick="this.value=this.value.replace(/[\n\r](?! \w)/gi,'');">Remove Spaces</button>
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')" >Copy</button></pre>

</body>
```

Comment: value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ''); try something like that

Comment: `<button onclick="this.value=...">` will try to alter the value of the button.

Comment: _empty lines removed_ ... or _all_ line-breaks removed? What you show for your `Copied/outputted text` is all line-breaks removed, which is not what you say in the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't realize my example didn't save correctly. End result should equal "Line 1 <br>Line 2" as opposed to "Line1 <br><br>Line 2". Hope that helps?

Comment: Great example, but I can't use this at work:    http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/remove-empty-lines/